SQL SELECT statement returning different values when columns in different order
I have a very weird SQL problem.
I am creating next.js project and using vercel postgres sql.
So when I call:
const result = await sql`
        SELECT isenabled FROM Chatbots WHERE id = ${chatbotId};
    `;

It returns { isenabled: true } as expected.
When I do:
SELECT isenabled, cssbubblestyles FROM Chatbots WHERE id = ${chatbotId};

it returns...
{ isenabled: true, cssbubblestyles: '' }

And that's incorrect, because in Vercel I clearly see it has a value.
Also in pgAdmin 4.
When I do:
SELECT isenabled, cssbubblestyles, internalname FROM Chatbots WHERE id = ${chatbotId};

It returns correctly:
{  isenabled: true,  cssbubblestyles: '#chatbot-launcher { background-color: #aaabbb; }', internalname: 'Chatbot' }

Why on earth calling it with just isenabled and cssbubblestyles returns only the first value and null?
What's the best part - when I change the order to cssbubblestyles, isenabled, it returns correct values...
Any ideas?


It is not returning NULL for cssbubblestyles is returning an empty string ''. 2) This needs more information. Add as text update to question text : a) Postgres version. b) Are you sure you are connecting to same database in each case. c) Do you  have table name case issues? In other words is the table name actuallyChatbot or some other case? d) Is id unique? 3) Crank up the logging in Postgres and see what is actually hitting the database.


Please provide an [mre]. With just the queries and the results, there isn't enough information to reproduce the problem. Having the full table DDL, including indexes, would be very helpful. The results of EXPLAIN(ANALYZE) for the queries might also prove useful. Is id unque? If not, then it's possible that some queries are being statisfied with index only scans and others with full table scans.

This is truly a bit weird. The first point of check should be the chatbotId variable in the query. If the chatbotId variable is consistent at every point of the query execution, the order of columns in the SELECT statement does not affect the underlying data or the result, it only determines the order in which the columns appear in the result.
The second point of check should be to confirm if the id is the primary key in the Chatbots table. If id is not the primary key (it means it isn't unique), we might have issues with duplicate rows where one of the rows is returning the empty string " " and the other is returning the '#chatbot-launcher { background-color: #aaabbb; }'.
For your use case and to ensure consistency, we can use DISTINCT to help with deduplication on the rows in the Chatbots table with that id.


   const result = await sql
                    `SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) isenabled, cssbubblestyles 
                     FROM Chatbots 
                     WHERE id = ${chatbotId}
                     ORDER BY id, created_at DESC;
                     `



This will give us the last created single row with the provided chatbotId
